# I want to make duplicate values in the set of array null

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am currently studying flutter and working on projects with other people.

I want to make duplicate values in the set of array null.

For example, if you already have the same date in front of you, you want to make the date output from the back null or ''.

I'm going to show you an example with a picture.

This is how we get the json data.

```
{result: SUCCESS, message: , data: [{sid: 48, userSid: 19, category: sales, reg_method: self, account_cd: 413, payment_type: invoice, bizno: 155151548, amount: 2000000, amount_supply: 1800000, tax_free_yn: Y, use_date: 231022, use_time: 1557, use_organization: 4},
{sid: 50, userSid: 19, category: purchase, reg_method: self, account_cd: 429, payment_type: invoice, bizno: 15584846518,amount: 900000, amount_supply: 810000, tax_free_yn: N, use_date: 231022, use_time: 1500, use_organization: 3}, 
{sid: 45, userSid: 19, category: sales, reg_method: self, account_cd: 418, payment_type: etc, bizno: 1557888888, amount: 7800000, amount_supply: 7800000, tax_free_yn: N, use_date: 230519, use_time: 1515, use_organization: 1},
{sid: 44, userSid: 19, category: sales, reg_method: self, account_cd: 418, payment_type: etc, bizno: 1557888888, amount: 7800000, amount_supply: 7800000, tax_free_yn: N, use_date: 230518, use_time: 1414,use_organization: 1}]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsIRZ.png)

These values mean that you're struggling like this because you can't change shape because you're bringing them to another external api.

I've been spending a day on this problem. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will help you:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ExampleClass> listItem = [
      ExampleClass(useDate: 231022, amount: 1000),
      ExampleClass(useDate: 231022, amount: 2000),
      ExampleClass(useDate: 230519, amount: 3000),
      ExampleClass(useDate: 230518, amount: 4000),
    ];
    return Material(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listItem.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              if (index == 0)
                Text("${listItem[index].useDate}")
              else if (listItem[index].useDate != listItem[index - 1].useDate)
                Text("${listItem[index].useDate}"),
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(Icons.add),
                  Text("${listItem[index].amount}"),
                ],
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleClass {
  final int useDate;
  final int amount;

  ExampleClass({required this.useDate, required this.amount});
}
```

Your class, which is mapped from JSON data, can replace the **ExampleClass**.